# Count duplicates in array list

Tags: java, arrays, java-6

```
Arraylist al = new ArrayList();

Random r = new Random();

int arr[] = new int[100];

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { // assuming the array variable is named arr...
    arr[i] = r.nextInt(200);
    al.add(arr[i]);
}
```

Output should be like this

```
Duplicates:2

Values 2 : count=4

Values 99: count=96
```

Without using hash things
Jdk 1.6_04

Comment: What’s the problem ? Are you asking for a Java 8 solution?

Comment: `al.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),Collectors.counting()))` then you can get count of each number.

Comment: Yes i need a java 8 Or older than java8

Answer (score 2):

A simpler solution would be:

```
al.stream().distinct()
                .forEach(v -> System.out.println("Values " + v + " : count=" + Collections.frequency(al, v)));
```

Get a stream consisting of the distinct elements then count the number of elements in the list with `Collections.frequency()`

Update: if you're not allowed to use features of java 8:

```
Set<Integer> distinctSet = new HashSet<>(al);
for(int i: distinctSet) {
    System.out.println("Valuess " + i + " : count=" + Collections.frequency(al, i));
}
```

Comment: Try <Integer> instead of <>

Comment: `Set<Integer> distinctSet = new HashSet<Integer>(al);`

Comment: Last question how bout not displaying the values that dont have duplicate.

Comment: Frequency should be greater than 1 to display so you can put a condition before `println()` :  `if (Collections.frequency(al, i) > 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to go about it:

```
new Random().ints(100, 0, 200) // 100 is streamSize , 0 is randomNumberOrigin, 200 is randomNumberBound
            .boxed()
            .collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(), counting()))
            .forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println("Values " + k + " count" + v));
```

or if you want the result in a list:

```
List<String> result = new Random().ints(100, 0, 200) // 100 is streamSize , 0 is randomNumberOrigin, 200 is randomNumberBound
                .boxed()
                .collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(), counting()))
                .entrySet().stream()
                .map(e -> "Values " + e.getKey() + " count" + e.getValue())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Another approach would be with `toMap`:

```
List<String> res = new Random().ints(100, 0, 200) // 100 is streamSize , 0 is randomNumberOrigin, 200 is randomNumberBound
                .boxed()
                .collect(toMap(Function.identity(), e -> 1, Math::addExact))
                .entrySet().stream()
                .map(e -> "Values " + e.getKey() + " count" + e.getValue())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Edit:**

given you've removed the Java 8 tag, here's a solution for completeness:

```
List<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>();
Set<Integer> accumulator = new HashSet<>();

Random r = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
     int result = r.nextInt(200);
     al.add(result);
     accumulator.add(result);
}

for (Integer i : accumulator) {
     System.out.println("Values " + i + " : count=" + Collections.frequency(al, i));
}
```

+1 to @Hülya for suggesting `Collections.frequency` first.

Comment: Function is not working and i realized that i have jdk 1.6_04

Comment: @JamesSshhh so my advice to you would be to make sure you tag the correct java version next time.

Comment: My Fault Im sorry.

Comment: I'd appreciate it men 

Comment: Im getting error in.     List<Integers> al = new ArrayList<>();